# entry point at web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have some web service , I have there  asmx  file with the  web service's functions.

Now I need also to open there an worker thread but I don't see there  any entry point like main or something like this .

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web service doesn't have any main. Web service is hosted in web server and it is instantiated when a client send a request to call one of its web methods - each request is processed in separate thread out of the box. I also don't think that custom worker thread in the environment where you don't have full control over application domain recycling (unless you turn everything off in IIS) is a good idea.

Comment: I need to bring some information from another applications , and update some structures that the web service is using , what is the best practice here ?

Comment: @Night Walker: Do you understand that this must be done within client request? You can simply use any asynchronous pattern in your web method but still your method must wait to be able to deliver response back to the client. The web service instance itself lives to serve single request and it is disposed after serving it - it is the same model as aspx web pages. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have some application that generates each time a list of massages , then I have a client that via web service need to get each time only one message from the list that was generated . I thought to pub all the massages to the web service and there deal with the logic , didn't know that after each call the web service is disposed . Can you recommend some design here ?

Comment: Generate messages into some database table which will work as a queue. When the client calls the service it will load and remove the oldest message from the table.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for application start event in global.asax ? AFAIK,This event fires on the very first request to your web service after a server restart.